# gdal can't import ogr

Tags: python, linux, gdal, ogr

I've written a python script that runs fine on one computer. but can't import ogr from osgeo on another. Both machines running linux, and have gdal compiled from source and both include with-python=yes in the config.

I have tried both:

> import ogr

and

> from osgeo import ogr

as I understand it, I shouldn't have to install anything extra besides gdal itself and pyton of course.

Comment: It means that this package (gdal) is not properly installed on the other machine.

Comment: Ith seems to be a "Python Path" issue.  Python libraries are looked-up within a defined path. Try

import sys
sys.path

Comment: I have recompiled and reinstalled gdal. the directory with the osgeo modules are showing in sys.path